# node.js mongoose update specific value in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e51809454115b7c5d593a4"),
    "usage" : {
        "from" : "2013-12-02T00:00:00+01:00",
        "to" : "2014-02-02T00:00:00+01:00",
        "used" : 674999999,
        "total" : NumberLong(4000000000)
    },
        "refills" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "RXh0cmEgU3VyZnZvbHlt",
            "amount" : 1000000000,
            "fee" : "5520",
            "feeVat" : "6900",
            "validTo" : "2014-02-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    ],
}
```

Where i would like to update the value "total" in "usage" and add to it the value "amount" in "refills"
All other values should be the same.

How do i do that best?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `refills` is an `object` and not an `array` as in your example:

```
coll.find( ..., function( err, result) {
    ...
    coll.update( ..., { $set: { 'refills.amount': ... } }, function( err,result ) {
        ...
    });
});
```

So you first have to read the specific document to get the value of `total` and then update the field `refills.amount`. You can use `$set` or `$inc` depending on how you want to update.

EDIT:

If `refills` is an `array` it is not that different. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array).

Comment: Hi, the thing is that refills is a array :/

Comment: How many array elements are there and do you know which one of them to update? If yes, where do you know?

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But `amount` of which array element? In an array there can be multiple...

Comment: Aa sorry in this case it will always be just one. Or the one with a specific "id"