# Updating an object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

From the client, I am able to pass the relevant _id (variable id is JPDCv6Wn6D94KSzMD for this example) of the particular object onto the method, along with a context variable that contains some words. I then wish to set the 'context' field with the context variable.

The summary object is located in meteor.user.profile

```
summary: Object
        _id: "JPDCv6Wn6D94KSzMD"
        context: ""
```

**The method: (the method attempts to update the 'summary' object but the function is not correct)**

```
Meteor.methods({
contentUpdate: function (context, id){
    Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId, //some function)}
}
});
```

The update method is what I'm having trouble with.

**Meteor.user(); console log:**

```
Meteor.user();
  Object {_id: "YZEBzkGZsny668N8o", emails: Array[1], profile: Object, username: "Mr.A"}
    _id: "YZEBzkGZsny668N8o"
    emails: Array[1]
    profile: Object
       name: "Mr A"
       summary: Object
          _id: "JPDCv6Wn6D94KSzMD"
          context: ""
        __proto__: Object
      __proto__: Object
    username: "Mr.A"
   __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand concerning your question, you need to do this:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId, 'profile.objectId': id},{$set:{'profile.$.text' : text}});
```

See additionally: [MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array)

Comment: I have updated the question to show where these fields are located. At the moment the code is not performing the update

Comment: yes, sorry I just changed the field values, so the code earlier did correspond to the values respectively

Comment: 'context' is a field within the summary object. The summary object is identified by the _id:

Comment: I replaced the id variable with the actual id value and the update does not take place.

Comment: @CodeCandy do a `Meteor.user()` in your client console(browser console) and add that logged output object to your question please.