# Mongo update array element (.NET driver 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

EDIT:
Not looking for the javascript way of doing this. I am looking for the MongoDB C# 2.0 driver way of doing this (I know it might not be possible; but I hope somebody knows a solution).

I am trying to update the value of an item embedded in an array on the primary document in my mongodb.

I am looking for a strongly typed way to do this. I am using the [Mongodb c# 2.0 driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/)

I can do it by popping the element, updating the value, then reinserting. This just doesn't feel right; since I am overwriting what might have been written in the meantime.

Here is what I have tried so far but with no luck:

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<TempAgenda> _collection;

void Main()
{
    var collectionName = "Agenda";
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Test");
    _collection = db.GetCollection<TempAgenda>(collectionName);
    UpdateItemTitle(1, 1, "hello");
}

public void UpdateItemTitle(string agendaId, string itemId, string title){
    var filter = Builders<TempAgenda>.Filter.Eq(x => x.AgendaId, agendaId);
    var update = Builders<TempAgenda>.Update.Set(x => x.Items.Single(p => p.Id.Equals(itemId)).Title, title);
    var result = _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Update an object in nested Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array)

Comment: @BlakesSeven that is not a c# question?

Comment: It's still the same principle. Match the array element in the query portion and use the positional `$` operator in the update portion. I didn't just randomly pull that out of a bag.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I can read the mongo documentation and do it with pure javascript, but, as I stated in my question, I am looking for the strongly typed way to do this and as far as I know embedding javascript strings in my C# code is not strongly typed.

Comment: There **still** is a positional operator for C#. It's not "javascript strings" it's "dot notation" and valid across all languages.

Comment: @BlakesSeven alright that sounds promising. Can you point me in the right direction; since I am failing to find this on my own. Hence the question above.

Comment: And heres the Documentation: [Update an Embedded Field](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/update/#update-an-embedded-field)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out as it doesn't appear to be mentioned in any of the official documentation (or anywhere else). I did however find [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531) on their issue tracker, which explains how to use the positional operator `$` with the C# 2.0 driver.

This should do what you want:

```
public void UpdateItemTitle(string agendaId, string itemId, string title){
    var filter = Builders<TempAgenda>.Filter.Where(x => x.AgendaId == agendaId && x.Items.Any(i => i.Id == itemId));
    var update = Builders<TempAgenda>.Update.Set(x => x.Items[-1].Title, title);
    var result = _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Result;
}
```

Notice that your `Item.Single()` clause has been changed to `Item.Any()` and moved to the filter definition.

`[-1]` or `.ElementAt(-1)` is apparently treated specially (actually everything < 0) and will be replaced with the positional operator `$`.

The above will be translated to this query:

```
db.Agenda.update({ AgendaId: 1, Items.Id: 1 }, { $set: { Items.$.Title: "hello" } })
```

Comment: Sorry for being so slow at accepting your answer. Works very well. Unfortunately they don't support more than one operational selectors: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 Seems weird to me, since this can be used to make a better isolation of the update needed to be done.

Comment: Thanks Søren.  I must say I am not a fan of the syntax they have chosen though because it means you cannot use IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T> and forces you to use the more cumbersome IList<T> or a simple array

Comment: @Buvy You should be able to use the LINQ extension method `ElementAt(-1)` as well.

Comment: @SørenKruse you are indeed correct while that syntax I just verified that works like a charm.  it is a little cumbersome compared to array indexer but at least I don't have to make all my domain classes use IList<T> which is what I was after.

Comment: I tried this solution and the code actually compiles without any error but what happens in runtime when I query the document, the [-1] in that array starts a reverse indexed search instead of using a positional operator.

So -1 results the last element of array, -2 gives second last. This isn't exactly what we want, indexing should be dynamic through positional operator.

Comment: @Suleman have you found any solution for every index matching update?

Comment: It's quite possible that doing `.Result` here will cause locking issues

Comment: use `x.Items.FirstMatchingElement().Title` instead of `[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this was helpful.  I have an addition though, I've used the above for arrays, pushing to a nested array and pulling from one.  The issue I have found is that if I had an int array (So not an object, just a simple int array) that the PullFilter didn't actually work - "Unable to determine the serialization information" which is strange as it's only an array of ints.  What I ended up doing was making it an array of objects with only one int parameter, and it all started to work.  Possibly a bug, or perhaps my lack of understanding. Anyway, as I've struggled to find information about pulling and pushing to nested object arrays with the C# 2.0 driver, I thought I should post my findings here, as they use the above syntax.

```
var filter = Builders<MessageDto>.Filter.Where(x => x._id == entity.ParentID && x.NestedArray.Any(i => i._id == entity._id));
var update = Builders<MessageDto>.Update.PullFilter(x => x.NestedArray.ElementAt(-1).User, Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(f => f.UserID, userID));
Collection<MessageDto>(currentUser).UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

And also:

```
var filter = Builders<MessageDto>.Filter.Where(x => x._id == entity.ParentID && x.NestedArray.Any(i => i._id == entity._id));
var update = Builders<MessageDto>.Update.Push(x => x.NestedArray.ElementAt(-1).Users, new User { UserID = userID });
Collection<MessageDto>(currentUser).UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: you are talking about an array of int, but the example is still with an array storing complex structures. Show an example of removing ONE element from an array of int.

Answer (score 2):

In newer drivers `ElementAt(-1)` might no longer be supported.  I have had code with (-1) that stopped working when going to `.NET6` and `MongoDB Driver 2.19.0`

They have introduced ExtensionMethods instead:

```
x.A.FirstMatchingElement() => "A.$"
x.A.AllElements() => "A.$[]"
x.A.AllMatchingElements("identifier") => "A.$[identifier]"
```

Comment: For those interested, this was documented in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4079

Answer (score 2):

Here's the combined working solution of the above answers with
**.NET 7**
and
**MongoDB.Driver 2.20.0**

Use `FirstMatchingElement()` or `AllElements()` instead of `[-1]`

- `AgnendaId` is the parent's
- `Items` is the NestedArray

---

Update the **FirstMatchingElement**:

```
public void UpdateItemTitle(string agendaId, string itemId, string title)
{
    var filter = Builders<TempAgenda>.Filter.Where(x => x.AgendaId == agendaId && x.Items.Any(i => i.Id == itemId));
    var update = Builders<TempAgenda>.Update.Set(x => x.Items.FirstMatchingElement().Title, title);

    _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Update **AllElements**:

```
public void UpdateItemTitle(string agendaId, string itemId, string title)
{
    var filter = Builders<TempAgenda>.Filter.Where(x => x.AgendaId == agendaId && x.Items.Any(i => i.Id == itemId));
    var update = Builders<TempAgenda>.Update.Set(x => x.Items.AllElements().Title, title);

    _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to update a Document or sub array is as follows:

```
var filter = Builders<Declaracion>.Filter.Where(x => x.Id == di && x.RemuneracionMensualActual.RemuneracionActIndustrial.Any(s => s.Id == oid));

        var update = Builders<Declaracion>.Update.Set(x => x.RemuneracionMensualActual.RemuneracionActIndustrial.ElementAt(-1).Ingreso, datos.ActividadIndustrial.Ingreso)
            .Set(x => x.RemuneracionMensualActual.RemuneracionActIndustrial.ElementAt(-1).RazonSocial, datos.ActividadIndustrial.RazonSocial)
            .Set(x => x.RemuneracionMensualActual.RemuneracionActIndustrial.ElementAt(-1).TipoNegocio, datos.ActividadIndustrial.TipoNegocio);
```

Comment: I think you got downvoted because somebody got upset by translation, "The correct way to..." reads as "this it the one true way" which somebody got offended with, and didn't even have the courtesy to leave a comment. I will say that your answer does duplicate 2 of the answers given above, where they use `[-1]` or `.ElementAt(-1)`.

Comment: Please do not spam an answer. We can all **clearly** see it has already been answered.