# MongoDB C# Driver projection $elemMatch $

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to translate this query from text-based filters to expression based.
Query part is OK, but I'm having troubles with projection `"state.transfer.attempts.$": 1`.

What is Expression equivalent for Project `$` ?

Thanks in advance

```
db.Items.find({
    "state.transfer.attempts": {
    "$elemMatch": {
          "entityId": 1,
          "state" : "failed"
        }
  }
},
{
  "state.transfer.attempts.$": 1
})
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](http://www.mattburkedev.com/updating-inside-a-nested-array-with-the-mongodb-positional-operator-in-c-number/), the positional operator is implemented by addressing the `-1th`-element:

`Builders<State>.Projection.Include(state => state.transfer.attempts[-1])`

or

`Builders<State>.Projection.Include(state => state.transfer.attempts.ElementAt(-1));`

The same solution is mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33720549/11956).

I've tried to find a reference of this behavior in the documentation, but without luck though.