# Error when trying to update MongoDb array element

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

In my Azure CosmosDb MongoApi I have JSON with an embed array of documents.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a95745df886842904b82f71"),
    "token": "value1",
    "channel": "value2",
    "urls":
    [
        {
            "url": "<url1>", 
            "interval": "<int>"
        },
        {
            "url": "<url2>"
            "interval": "<int>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update "interval" field in a specific array element. Problem is when I use solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453681/mongo-update-array-element-net-driver-2-0) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating), I end up with an exception:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed: Invalid BSON field name 'urls.$.interval'.
```

So, I decided to try running queries in Mongo Shell and got the same error:

```
{
    "nMatched": 0,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "writeError": 
    {
        "code": 2,
        "errmsg": "Invalid BSON field name 'urls.$.interval'"
    }
}
```

Here is my C# code:

```
    var filterBuilder = Builders<User>.Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Where(p => p.Token == model.Token && p.Channel == model.Channel && p.Urls.Any( u => u.Url == model.Url));
    var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set(p => p.Urls.ElementAt(-1).interval, 5);
    await _context.Users.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<User>(filter, update);
```

Here is my MongoDb shell request:

```
db.Users.update( {"urls.interval": 60}, {$set: {"urls.$.interval": 30}} );
```

My question is what is causing this exception and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did you try `db.Users.update( {"Urls.interval": 60}, {$set: {"Urls.$.interval": 30}} );` ?

Comment: @mickl Yep, sorry, formatting error, in my JSON schema I have "urls" lower case. I'll update the question right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional operator is not currently supported by Cosmos DB. Please use the following workaround: iterate over documents and array elements on the client side, change the required element and issue an update on the document with new array:
 
    For example, assuming you have a collection users of following elements:

> ```
> { 
>     "_id" : ObjectId("59d6b719708b990d6c9b3aca"), 
>     "tags" : [
>         {
>             "id" : 1, 
>             "value" : "11"
>         }, 
>         {
>             "id" : 2, 
>             "value" : "22"
>         }, 
>         {
>             "id" : 3, 
>             "value" : "32"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

…you can issue the following command to get one of the elements (with id=1 in this case) updated:

> ```
> db.users.find().forEach( 
>         function(user) 
>         { 
>          user.tags.forEach( 
>          function(tag) 
>          {
>                if (tag.id=="1")
>                {
>                        tag.value = "Updated!";                          
>                        db.users.updateOne({_id : user._id}, {$set: {"tags": user.tags}});
>                }
>         }
>         );
>        }  
> );
> ```

You can adjust the condition in if() with even finer granularity than positional operator allows.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped!