# Update a nested document filed and increment in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update a nested document filed if present increment an old value with new value or insert a new document.

## Data

```
New Zealand,Waikato,Hamilton,1004
New Zealand,Waikato,Auckland,145
New Zealand,Otago,Dunedin,1068
```

## Json

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e7d2a72f68907c17cfcb2f"), "country" : "New Zealand", 
"regions" : [ { "region" : "Waikato", "size" : 1004 }, 
{ "region" : "Waikato", "size" : 145 }, { "region" : "Otago", "size" : 1068 } ] }
```

In document `regions` array is dynamic in nature. In above document I need to update an increment field `size` value of ~Waikato`.  Instead of putting an another record in array of regions.

## My code

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("country", "New Zealand");
query.put("regions.$.region", "Waikato");
BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject().append("$inc", new BasicDBObject().append("regions.$.size", 145));
BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
command.put("$set", data);
collection.update(query, command, true, false);
```

## I need output like these:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e7d2a72f68907c17cfcb2f"), "country" : "New Zealand", "regions" : [ { "region" : "Waikato", "size" : 1149 }, { "region" : "Otago", "size" : 1068 } ] }
```

Please suggest me on these issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Update an object in nested Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator only belongs in the "update portion and not the query. Also you need to `.append()` in the query otherwise you overwrite:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("country", "New Zealand");
query.append("regions.region", "Waikato");

BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject()
    .append("$inc", new BasicDBObject().append("regions.$.size", 145));

collection.update(query, update, true, false);
```

Basically looks like this ( shell wise ) :

```
collection.update(
    { "country": "New Zealand", "regions.region": " "Waikato" },
    { "$inc": regions.$.size": 145 },
    true,
    false
)
```