# Yii2 : How to update an object in nested array of mongodb from yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have structure like this

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "insert": [{
        "id": "23",
        "data": "abc"
    }, {
        "id": "56",
        "data": "xyz"
    }]
}
```

Now I wanted to add the object into insert field and remove the object from insert field what is way to write a query that will do this in yii2

Comment: you should read [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show your research and efforts.  And, have you tried [yii/mongodb](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html) ?

Comment: Sorry as I am begginer on stack overflow,I tried and your mention link and able to insert the record into mongo db,also able to update the fields but unable to update the multilevel fields.

Comment: i'm not familiar with PHP or Yii, to be honest, but in the mongo shell [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10523963/4207875) from another question, there is a really nice example of the syntax to do so, i hope it is of any help.

Comment: I am able to do it from directly mongo command,I am looking for using yii2's active record for that so I ask question.

Comment: I've checked the ActiveQuery class api, seems the asArray() method could return the "insert" contents. I can't try myself, but, you could give a try on chaining a where() after asArray() to see if you could access the documments, pretty much like a subselect in SQL

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to do, sorry! Are you trying to update multiple related records from a single form?

Comment: I wanted to update a nested array in document of mongodb using yii2 active record