# how to add another data in mongoose subdocument array using Angularjs and Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Here i need to add couple of address for a user, while registration itself user will add one address, after that if user willing to another address he can.

Now i need to know how to add another address in mongoose subdocument array using angularjs and nodejs

this is my exsiting json for user

[image: Json Image]

How can i add another in address array

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array

Comment: I need to add not to update

Comment: You have to use $push in update .

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: It is better to use $addToSet instead of $push, which is referred in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({"email" : "ealai@excrin.com"},{
    $push : { 
                "address" : {
                    "flat_no"   : "102",
                    "street"    : "New My Street Details",
                    "city"      : "My City",
                    "_id"       : "My Id"
                } 
            }
})
```

This command help u to update yr existing user address @kalai

Comment: db is yr database connections object name

Comment: @Kalai if the answer suits you, please don't forget to validate the answer so further people will get the answer right.