# How to update an array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema of highlight as:

```
var newshighlightSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    volumeNo:String,
    week:String,
    status:String,
    adminApp : Boolean,
    reviewerApp:Boolean,
    ttheadApp:Boolean,
    comment:String,

    highlight:[{
            createdby:String,
            level : String,
            title : String,
            description: String        
            }]
});
```

the following data is already present in db:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("580daa749c6e2e1830a54fe5"),
        "volumeNo" : "100",
        "week" : "W44Y2016",
        "status" : "false",
        "adminApp" : false,
        "reviewerApp" : false,
        "ttheadApp" : false,
        "comment" : "",
        "highlight" : [
                {
                        "createdby" : "58047db9f8995a147ce3fmeo",
                        "level" : "Accolades",
                        "title" : " the news title",
                        "description" : "Description of news title",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("580daa749c6e2e1830a54fe6")
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to  update the `title and description` of `object id =580daa749c6e2e1830a54fe6` above data.

I made a static function in model like this:

```
newshighlightSchema.statics.updateLevel=function(savedata, callback){ 
        console.log("data is model updating ",savedata);

    this.update({'highlight._id':savedata._id},{'$set':{
        'highlight.title':savedata.title,
        'highlight.description':savedata.description
    }},function(err){
        callback(err,null);
        console.log("Err in updating",err);
    })
}
```

the savedata in above funtion is:

```
savedata = { createdby: '58047db9f8995a147ce3fmeo',
  timestamp: 'Monday, 24th October 2016',
  testlabel: 'qq',
  level: 'Accolades',
  title: 'Updated news title',
  description: 'updated Description',
  _id: '580daa749c6e2e1830a54fe6',
   }
```

This is not working in mongoose. Any idea?
**Please note that I want to do this in mongoose. Not in mongodb client. **

Answer (score 0):

Use $,

```
 this.update({'highlight._id':savedata._id},{'$set':{
       'highlight.$.title':savedata.title,
        'highlight.$.description':savedata.description
  }},function(err){
```

cf : [Update nested mongo array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating)

Comment: Earlier I tried that also putting "$" doesn't help. It is still not updating.

Comment: maybe a problem with the _id fields, try to use ObjectId : const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; {'highlight._id':  new ObjectId(savedata._id)},