# Update the specific element in tags using mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

How can I update the specific element in tags using **mongodb** in **nodejs** ?

1. I want to update the second element of subject tag which has name
   called waseem,
2. Whose id is `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931")}`.
3. I want to change "gaming" as a "Bootstrap".

Can anyone give me a solution? Thanks in advance ...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58676ed1fc38461d8c5ff424"), "name" : "viki", "age" : 30, "subject" : [ "c", "node.js", "java" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5867710d30b158057c896974"), "name" : "bv", "age" : 29, "subject" : [ "c++", "Android", "java" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931"), "name" : "waseem", "age" : 30, "subject" : [ "c++", "gaming", "java" ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in a collection called users, you can do this.

In the `mongo` shell:

```
db.users.update(
  { _id: ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931") }, 
  { $set: { 'subject.1': 'gaming' } }
);
```

Using the Node.js `mongodb` driver:

```
var mondodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

  db.users.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931") }, 
    { $set: { 'subject.1': 'gaming' } }
  );

});
```

And finally, with `mongoose` you can do:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('./path/to/your/user/model');

User.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931") }, 
    { $set: { 'subject.1': 'gaming' } }
  );
```

Note that object ids are unique so you don't need to specify the name if you have the object id already. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating) for some details..

`'subject.1'` means the 'second element of the subject array'.

Comment: if we use objectid ,it shows objectid is not defined,without using objectid I used only name for refer the tags.it produces result.Thanks bro..

Comment: If you are using mongoose you can do `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931") ` instead of looking by name, which might not be unique.  If you are using the `mongodb` Node.js driver you can do `mongodb.ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931") `;

Answer (score 0):

Use positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator which identifies an element in an array, without having to know its positional value..

```
db.collection.update(
 {"name":"waseem", "_id" : ObjectId("5867713194f9f71a78bd9931"),"subject":"gaming"}, 
 { $set:{"subject.$":"Bootstrap"}}
)
```

Comment: if  we use objectid ,it shows objectid is not defined,without using objectid I used only name for refer the tags.it produces result.Thanks bro..

Comment: I've used it as you've mentioned it in the question. Anyway, good to know that it's working. Happy coding :)