# findAndUpdate array of objects overwrites the whole subscehama

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I searched all stackoverflow, but didn't find anything that solves my problem.

This is my mongoose user schema:

```
name: String,
movies: [new Schema({
  state: String,
  rate: String,
  note: String
})]
```

For example I want to update `note` to `test` in movie with `_id: 20` here. But I don't want to send the whole movie object that contains all `rate`, `state` and `note` values.

```
name: Mehdi,
movies: [
  {
    _id: 10,
    note: 'This is awesome',
    rate: 10
  },
  {
    _id: 20,
    rate: 7
  }
]
```

This is my current code:
It overwrites the whole movie object.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: user._id,
  'movies._id': 20
}, {
  $set: {
    'movies.$': movie
  }
}, {
  new: true
})
```

Should I `find` and then do it with plain JS and then `.save()` it?

It's not exact question as [MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating). Because I don't want to send the whole object. I may just want to send

```
_id: 10,
state: 'watched'
```

P.S.
I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-patch-update) plugin, but it has no workaround for specific object in array.

Comment: So you mean `$set: { 'movies.$.note': 'test' }`. This is what the [documentation does tell you](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) to do.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't want to send complete movie object. You say I should do:
`'movies.$.note': movie.note, 'movies.$.state': movie.state, 'movies.$.rate' : movie.rate`
?

Comment: I say, the documentation says, and the duplicate says that is so. Yes that is the syntax. Name each property via "dot notation" unless your intention is to to actually replace the whole object.

Comment: @NeilLunn So I'm not missing anything? there is actually no way that I can just send `{_id: 10, state: ''watched"}` and have an "updated" object?

Comment: I think you might be missing quite a bit. Perhaps take a rest from this for a while. Then come back and read the referenced answers and documentation and spend a little time practicing exercises and understanding it. It's pretty simple stuff but you are clearly missing the point.  Come back with fresh eyes.

Comment: @NeilLunn Man, I'm so confused 