# MeteorJS : UPDATE AN OBJECT inside array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm trying to update the **comment_delete = 'false'** to **'true'** on  the second object within an array. Help Please ....

```html
 

"_id" : "jLkRdxocZzheefWF3",
 "comments" : [
  {
   "comment_id" : "\u0003624334",
   "comment" : " test",
   "user" : "peter pan",
   "userId" : "MQtp4i8bZeLYSLbr5",
   "comment_delete" : "false"
  },
  {
   "comment_id" : "\u0007973101",
   "comment" : " add",
   "user" : "peter pan",
   "userId" : "MQtp4i8bZeLYSLbr5",
   "comment_delete" : "false"
  }
 ],
 
}
```

Comment: `comments[1].comment_delete = true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
db.collection.update(
{_id:"jLkRdxocZzheefWF3"}, //add your first match criteria here, keep '{}' if no filter needed.
{$set:{"comments.$[element].comment_delete":"true"}},
{arrayFilters:[{"element.comment_id":"\u0007973101"}]}
)
```

I dont have an idea about your match criteria since you didnt mention it in the question. Change them as per your requirements. This change `comment_delete` to `true` as per the `comment_id` mentioned.

Output is:

```
{
"_id" : "jLkRdxocZzheefWF3",
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "comment_id" : "\u0003624334",
        "comment" : " test",
        "user" : "peter pan",
        "userId" : "MQtp4i8bZeLYSLbr5",
        "comment_delete" : "false"
    }, 
    {
        "comment_id" : "\u0007973101",
        "comment" : " add",
        "user" : "peter pan",
        "userId" : "MQtp4i8bZeLYSLbr5",
        "comment_delete" : "true"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul , but  I'm still having some error updating, 


update failed: MongoError: cannot use the part (comments of comments.$[test].comment_delete) to traverse the element ({comments: [ { comment_id: "\u0007973101"......

Comment: U need to have mongo version 3.6. And the query should be executed from mongo shell (just in case if you're using third party tool). The above query is tested and its working on my local. Secondly, I dont  answer based on your demand (you have un-selected my answer to get instant reply from me).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.update({'_id':'jLkRdxocZzheefWF3',"comments.comment_id":"\u0007973101"},{$set:{'comments.$.comment_delete':true}})
```

1. Try above mentioned query it works