# update nested array with arrayFilters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've seen example like [this](https://www.mattburkedev.com/updating-inside-a-nested-array-with-the-mongodb-positional-operator-in-c-number/) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating) where we can easily use the positionnal $ operator to update an object in an array.

I'm trying to do the same thig but I must use an object sub-property.

Exemple:

```
// Data model:
UserSchema = new Schema({
permissionsPerOrganization: [{
    organization: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Organization'
    },
    role: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Role'
    }
}],
```

I must update Role in `permissionsPerOrganization` with an exact _id.

Here is what I have:

```
this.activeSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id, 'permissionsPerOrganization.organization._id': org._id },
    { 'permissionsPerOrganization.$.role': roleId },
    {
        new: true
    })
```

I also have tried with the new [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) syntax which seem made for that kind of use case but it fails...

Have you got a clue please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) in following way

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": user._id }, 
  { "$set": { "permissionsPerOrganization.$[array].role": roleId  }},
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "array.organization": org._id }], new: true }
)
```

Comment: Wow !! Thank you, I think I was misunderstanding the concept of object._id

Comment: Sorry, spoke a bit too quick...this doesn't update nothing in my collection but doesn't throw error...

Comment: You need to cast your id to `ObjectId` then it will definitely work