# MongoDB: how to update a specific object inside array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

i need address in first one object update if object id not match then insert in address array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0707d856cd5a1abcb7832f"), 
    "address" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e0727e87a21f51d3c5bf3bb"),
            "fulladdress" : "aa",
            "location" : "aa",
            "name" : "aa",
            "landMark" : "aa"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e0727e87a21f51d3c5bf3bb"),
            "fulladdress" : "bb",
            "location" : "bb",
            "name" : "bb",
            "landMark" : "bb"
        }
    ], 
}
```

I have nested object like: `{ _id: 122, nested: [ { _id: 1, name: 1 }, { _id: 2, name: 2 } ] }`.

I need if nested object getting `{ _id: 2, name: 2 }` object then it will update like `{ _id: 2, name: 5 }` is change otherwise append the document like

`{ _id: 123, nested: { _id:1, name: 1 }, { _id: 2, name: 2 }, { id: 3, name: 3 } ] }`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, is there a query that you've tried that isn't working?  Can you provide both a sample input document and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: sorry. i have nested object like "{_id:122,nested:[{_id:1,name:1},{_id:2, name:2}]}". I need if nested object getting "{_id:2,name:2}"  object then it will update like "{_id:2,name:5}" is change otherwise append the document like "{_id:123, nested:{_id:1,name:1},{_id:2, name:2},{id:3,name:3}]}".

Comment: Here is an example of updating a nested object based on a query condition: [Update Specific Elements of an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents).

Comment: Here is the solution you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024670/11082661