# MongoDB add field to an object inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an object user that looks like that

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edbdf57ac52325464b054ec"),
    ...
    "purchaseHistory" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ee7a8f6b438a1254cec3f74"),
        ...
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ee7a8f6b438a1254cec3f88"),
        ...
        }
    ]
}
```

What I wanna do is to add a new field to a specific object inside "purchaseHistory" by ID, for example I wanna add to "5ee7a8f6b438a1254cec3f88" a field "status": 0

What  I tried is

```
users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: ObjectId(userId),
        'purchaseHistory._id': ObjectId(saleId)
    },
    {
        $set: { 'purchaseHistory.$.status': status}
    }
)
```

But it gives me an error, how can I do it properly?

Comment: "it gives me an error". What Error?

Comment: @AyushGupta the error was because I called it from a different function and I missed the userId :) I didn't see that but I fixed it after I read the error by using try & catch, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating) Marking it as dup..

Comment: @whoami yes thank you (:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MongoDB provides the [positional update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the website provided by D. SM, I was able to do it this way

```
users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        '_id': ObjectId(userId),
        'purchaseHistory._id': ObjectId(saleId)
    },
    {
        $set: { 'purchaseHistory.$.status': status }
    }
)
```